# custom method to concat string vs not using that method

Tags: java, performance

I have a code like this:

```
private static final String BR_TAG = "<br/>";

private ResourceBundle rb;

public String create(){
   String result = addLine("some text");
   result = addLine("some text");
   result = addLine("some text");
   ....
}

public String addLine(String text){
    return rb.getString(text) + BR_TAG; 
}
```

This is my current code, but is it optimal? Maybe I shouldn't use separate method to add line to my result? I could to this like this without method addLine:

```
public String create(){
   String result = rb.getString("some text") + BR_TAG;
   result = rb.getString("some text") + BR_TAG;
   result = rb.getString("some text") + BR_TAG;
   ....
}
```

Or I can think about third option with passing StringBuilder to my method:

```
public String create(){
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   addLine("some text", sb);
   addLine("some text", sb);
   ....
}

public void addLine(String text, StringBuilder sb){
    sb.append(rb.getString(text)).append(BR_TAG); 
}
```

What do you think which option is the best?

Comment: Per your third option, `StringBuilder.apend()` doesn't return a `String`, it returns the instance of `StringBuilder`.

Comment: StringBuilder will usually be the superior option compared to just concatenating strings. The thing you should probably ask yourself is: Why the heck do I even have markup in my Java code. It is usually best to keep markup (HTML) separated from actual source code, so consider moving to JSP or some other form of template engine.

Comment: @avojak I know, sry it was quick copy paste ;)

Comment: @Till Helge You are right, but I have no choice I'm implementing some interface to send mails that requires returning String with whole content of mail.

Comment: @KamilRuszczyk Nothing prevents you from extracting the markup into some form of template and working with that instead. I do realize that corporate requirements sometimes don't allow for clean solutions, but in this case it should not be that hard. ;) But sending mails always is all kinds of "fun", so good luck with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use another method?

IMO, neither is the best, in terms of the beauty of the code. But in terms of performance, the third is better because a `StringBuilder` takes less time than the `+` when used a lot of times.

To make your code look prettier, Maybe make use of the Builder Pattern?

```
public class LineBuilder {
    private StringBuilder builder;
    private static final String BR_TAG = "<br/>";

    public LineBuilder() {
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public LineBuilder addLine(String text) {
        builder.append(text).append(BR_TAG);
        return this;
    }

    public String build() {
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

You can also add other methods like `addHeader` or `addStrong` that adds in `<h1>` and `<strong>` tags.

And you can use it like this:

```
String result = new LineBuilder()
    .addLine("Hello")
    .addLine("World")
    .addLine("Bye!")
    .build();
```

That just looks better!